# Alternating a int array efficiently

Tags: java

I have a quick little program that will take an `int[]` and alternate the biggest numbers in it with the smallest numbers.

It is worth noting that this program only has to deal with an `int[]` whose length is an even number.

Is there a faster way of completing the alternation of the array without copying the two halves of the array into separate arrays and then merging them back together into the initial array?

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {
    public void run() {
        int[] arr = {1, 9, 14, 12, 2, 5, 8, 7, 3, 6, 4, 13, 10, 11};
        Arrays.sort(arr);

        int length = arr.length;
        int length2 = length / 2;

        int[] cA = new int[length2];
        int[] dA = new int[length2];

        int c = 0;

        System.arraycopy(arr, 0, cA, 0, length2);
        System.arraycopy(arr, length2, dA, 0, length2);

        for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            if(i % 2 == 0) {
                arr[i] = cA[c];
            } else {
                arr[i] = dA[c];
                c++;
            }
        }

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main().run();
    }
}
```

The expected output of the example above would be

```
[1, 8, 2, 9, 3, 10, 4, 11, 5, 12, 6, 13, 7, 14]
```

Comment: What's the expected output? please give an example

Comment: @ÓscarLópez Added one. Sorry about forgetting to include

Comment: Yes and there is a faster way to do the above too, unroll that loop by 2 so you can get rid of the `if` inside it.

Comment: @harold Sorry if it's obvious but I'm not sure what you mean by "unroll the loop"

Comment: Do two iterations from the old loop in one iteration of the new loop. So bicrement i and do `arr[i] = cA[c]; arr[i + 1] = dA[c++];` - no `if` necessay

Comment: In your question, you mean that length is an _even_ number, right? not an "equal" number

Comment: @ÓscarLópez Whoops

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a much simpler version:

```
    int n = arr.length;
    int middle = n / 2;
    int[] output = new int[n];

    for (int i = 0; i < middle; i++){
        output[2 * i] = arr[i];
        output[2 * i + 1] = arr[i + middle];
    }
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/T9nQe9)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the input array has en even length, we can do a single pass over the original array, traversing the first half and then the second half, copying the values in the right places.

Notice that we don't even have to use `System.arraycopy()`, and creating a new array for the output comes in handy:

```
int n = arr.length;
int middle = n / 2;
int[] output = new int[n];

for (int i = 0; i < middle; i++)
    output[2 * i] = arr[i];
for (int i = middle; i < n; i++)
    output[2 * (i - middle) + 1] = arr[i];
```

The result is as expected:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(output));
=> [1, 8, 2, 9, 3, 10, 4, 11, 5, 12, 6, 13, 7, 14]
```

Comment: Not sure why you wrote 2 * (i - middle) + 1 when the following works: Its the simplest. http://ideone.com/T9nQe9

Comment: Yes, that's the simplest one. I wrote it like that for leaving the `arr[i]` part the same on both of my loops.

Answer (score 1):

You can lower the amount of loops you are doing by taking advantage of the half split in your `cA` and `dA` arrays:

```
for(int c = 0; c < length2; c++) {
    arr[c*2] = cA[c];
    arr[c*2 + 1] = dA[c];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Adapting @Oscar 's solution a bit, we can reduce the number of loops to half.

```
    int n = arr.length;
    int middle = n / 2;
    int[] output = new int[n];

    for (int i = 0, j = middle; i < middle; i++, j++){
        output[2 * i] = arr[i];
        output[2 * (j - middle) + 1] = arr[j];
    }
```

Comment: Also, notice that the loop condition can be simplified to just: `i < middle` (or `j < n` , it's the same)

Comment: @ÓscarLópez : True that! Thank You.